# Dimension of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying linear algebra and am new to the concept of vector subspaces, dimensions and basis. I know that a vector space can have more than one different basis, but its dimension (the number of vectors in each basis) is always fixed. However could you clarify if there is any relation between two different basis?

A related question is also given below:

W is a subspace of V s.t. dim(W) = dim(V) where dim means dimension. Is W = V?

Comment: A subspace can have infinitely many different bases. However, the one thing common to all of them is the number of vectors in each basis. The number of vectors in every basis for a particular subspace is the same as the dimension of the subspace.

Comment: Take $\mathbb{R}^2$ and consider different bases in the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation between different basis is only that they have the same cardinality.

For your second question: You may conclude $W=V$ if the dimensions are *finite*: Note that a basis of $W$ is linearly idependent and hence can be extended to a baiss of $V$; by $\dim W=\dim V$ this "extension" is trivial, i.e. we already have a basis of $V$.

Comment: @ Hagen . Thanks but could you please explain how any vector v added to basis of W can be proven to be linear combination of basis of W itself thereby making the ëxtension" you mentioned trivial? Béçause if I have understood correctly, there can be two different basis with same dimension yet they can span different subspaces.